# I want to generate a uml diagram in netbeans

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, uml

I have created a project with servlets, jsps, and Java for an e-commerce website. In regards to the documentation I wanted to know if there is a way to create sequence diagrams and class diagrams using netbeans. The version I'm using is netbeans 7.3 but I couldn't find any information about it. Please can someone tell me how to install or even if it's possible to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want Netbeans to automatically generated UML diagrams for you like some other IDEs can, sadly netbeans cant do that and Netbeans 6.7 was the last version to support UML. However you could **download a [plugin](http://netbeans.org/features/uml/)** that will allow you to model UML diagrams in netbeans 7.3. When it comes to sequence diagrams even [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/features/uml/) themselves advise you to use [JDeveloper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/overview/index.html).

> Looking for a full featured, free UML modeling environment? JDeveloper provides comprehensive modeling capabilities that include:
>
> - UML diagrams like Use Case, Class, Activity and Sequence Diagrams

So I'd advise you to look for tools that are tailored to the task rather than trying to accomplish everything using netbeans.